# spring-boot ConcurrencyFailureException oracle

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a code, that when an error returns from a procedure, I need to update a table column in oracle. However, at the time of the update (inside the catch block), the following error occurs:

org.springframework.dao.ConcurrencyFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE TB_XPTO SET COLUMN_XPTO = XX WHERE ID_XPTO = ?]; ORA-02091: transação repetida
; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransactionRollbackException: ORA-02091:

My code:

```
                 try {
                                             
                     jdbcTemplate.update ("call PROCEDURE_XPTO(?)", ID_XPTO);                

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE TB_XPTO SET COLUMN_XPTO = XX WHERE ID_XPTO = ?", idXpto);
                     
                 }
```

My data source Config class

```
@Bean
public DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder(Environment springEnvironment) {
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server:1521/database.com.br");
    dataSourceBuilder.username("user");
    dataSourceBuilder.password("pass");
    return dataSourceBuilder;
}

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource(DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder) {
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: The error seems pretty clear: [ORA-02291: integrity constraint violated-parent key not found](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_02291_integrity_constraint_string_string_violated_parent_key_not_found.htm): you are trying to update a child without a matching parent, as defined by a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, but worked for me, using @Transactional, in the method that calls the procedure

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer, but worked for me, using @Transactional, in the method that calls the procedure.